# Angular ui-router state is not loaded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I have started to learn angular for a couple of days now and I gotta say it has been a bumpy road.I'm not new to SPA apps I have been working for the past year on a project that used Durandal.

In two days I will have to start working on a project that will use angular and angular-ui-router.

For some reason I can not seem to be able to configure not even the most simplest examples  found on angular-ui-router docs : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

As of now I have the following code:

This is my javascript code:

```
<script>
   var codeArtApp = angular.module("codeArtApp", ['ui.router']);

   codeArtApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($state){
       $state.go('contacts')

   });

   codeArtApp.config(function($stateProvider){
        $stateProvider.state('contacts', {
            template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
            resolve: { title: 'My Contacts' },
            controller: function($scope, title){
                $scope.title = 'My Contacts';
            },
            onEnter: function(title){
                console.log(title)
            },
            onExit: function(title){
                if(title){

                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

This is my html:

```
<body ng-app="codeArtApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <section ui-view></section>
</div>
</body>
```

When I run the app $state.go('contacts') gets executed but I am not being sent to contacts state and the html is not loaded.

If I try to load the state threw the browser url /#/contacts still nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have also binded the $stateChangeError event and I see I am getting a stack trace:

[image]

It seems it is trying to resolve "My ContactsProvider" but I named the state contacts what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrWS3tjn3gRfMEDC2QW5?p=preview). The changes which we have to do are:

Firstly we have to

1. declare the `url : '/'` parameter, belonging the any state and
2. we won't be using `controller="..."` setting, this is not how the states are evaluated with `ui-router`

Secondly we have to correctly use `resolve` functionality which must be as [doc says](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

> #### Resolve
>
> ... The `resolve` property is a map object. The map object contains key/value pairs of:
>
> key – `{string}`: a name of a dependency to be injected into the controller.
>       factory - `{string|function}`:
>
> - **If string, then it is an alias for a service.**
> - Otherwise if function, then it is injected and the return value is treated as the dependency. If the result is a promise, it is resolved before the controller is instantiated and its value is injected into the controller.

So as we can see, in resolve object we can return string, but as a name of service

This is the adjusted [and working](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrWS3tjn3gRfMEDC2QW5?p=preview) script:

```
'use strict';

var codeArtApp = angular.module("codeArtApp", ['ui.router']);

// NOT NEEDED
// codeArtApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($state) {
//  $state.go('contacts')    
// });

codeArtApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('contacts', {
    url : "/",
    template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
    resolve: {
      // title: 'My Contacts'
      title: function() { return 'My Contacts'; },
    },
    controller: function($scope, title) {
      $scope.title = 'My Contacts';
    },
    onEnter: function(title) {
      console.log(title)
    },
    onExit: function(title) {
      if (title) {

      }
    }
  })
});
```

This way we will trigger the default state

```
codeArtApp.config(['$urlRouterProvider',
  function($urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  }
]);
```

And this is the html template:

```
  <body ng-app="codeArtApp">        
    <!--<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
       <section ui-view></section>
    </div> -->        

    <section ui-view></section>    
  </body>
```

Check the code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrWS3tjn3gRfMEDC2QW5?p=preview)

Comment: Thanx..you answered more then one question I had on my mind besides the current problem...funny part is the example was taken from there wiki page that you also provided

Comment: Great to see that it helped anyhow. Enjoy the awesome `ui-router` ... ;)